# El significado de "otorgante u otorgantes"

Tags: significado

Quisiera preguntar sobre el significado de "[otorgante u otorgantes](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escritura_p%C3%BAblica)" en "una escritura pública es un documento público en el que se realiza ante un notario público (quien funge como ministro de fe) un determinado hecho o un derecho autorizado por dicho fedatario público, que firma con el otorgante u otorgantes, mostrando sobre la capacidad jurídica del contenido y de la fecha en que se realizó."

Según Diccionario panhispánico del español jurídico, "[otorgante](https://dpej.rae.es/lema/otorgante)" significa "persona que otorga la escritura u otro documento formal". ¿Quiere decir entonces que el fedatario público y el origante u otorgantes son de la misma persona? Pero en este caso la parte del párrafo donde dice "... dicho fedatario público, que firma con el otorgante u otorgantes" no tendrá sentido alguno, ¿no es así? ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

"... *dicho fedatario público, que firma con el otorgante u otorgantes*"

El otorgante u otorgantes (plural) aquí son aquellos que prestan su consentimiento en el acto de firmar ante el fedatario público.

- **Fedatario público** Notario o funcionario que tiene autoridad y competencia para aprobar o confirmar la autenticidad de un documento.
- Los "otorgantes", "strictus sensus" (sentido estricto), serían las partes implicadas, por ejemplo comprador y vendedor. En "sensu lato" (sentido amplio) también sería el notario. En ese ejemplo las partes, comprador y vendedor (otorgantes), que llegan a un acuerdo adaptándose que firman junto al notario **otorgando** (dando) este también su consentimiento.

1. Otorgar - Dar su consentimiento.
2. Otorgar - Consentir , Condescender o Conceder en este caso un derecho.
3. Partes Otorgantes - Aquellos que dan su consentimiento.

**En resumen**;

- Tenemos por una parte el otorgamiento por parte del Notario en un acto jurídico que tiene por motivo conceder o consentir la aparición de unos nuevos derechos y obligaciones para las partes.
- Por otra parte tenemos otro otorgamiento o consentimiento por las partes (comprador y vendedor) para obtener y aceptar cada uno de ellos sus nuevos derechos y nuevas obligaciones.

---

Pero vamos por partes;

El "**Otorgamiento**" es la acción de conceder o consentir un derecho en un acto, junto con la acción de formalizarlo en un documento, normalmente en escritura pública ante el notario.

La acción de conceder un derecho y formalizarlo en documento público la tiene solo el Estado que se vale de un Notario al que el Estado reconoce como intermediario para dar fe pública de esa concesión y de **su consentimiento**  que formaliza en acto de escritura y para que conste, en su caso, también en el Registro.

*La acción de **otorgar**, conceder o consentir ese derecho y de formalizarlo en documento público la tiene el notario, siendo los **otorgantes** los que dan o prestan igualmente su consentimiento para recibir esa **otorgación**, concesión o consentimiento por parte del notario de los nuevos derechos y exigencias (obligaciones) que se derivan de este acto jurídico, de ahí la confusión.*

El **otorgante u otorgantes** (a los que se les va a reconocer "**el otorgamiento**" de esos derechos, es decir, la acción de consentir o conceder esos derechos) son aquellos que van a recibir o a los que se les va a conceder un derecho, **por ejemplo ser propietario/s de una casa**, "**obtener el dinero de la venta de la casa**" y por tanto han de dar o prestar su consentimiento para recibir esas concesiones u otorgamientos, identificándose con sus datos y estampando la firma de acuerdo ante el notario.

Una vez leído el documento por parte del notario y dado el consentimiento por parte de los otorgantes (de recibir esa "**otorgación**" o derecho de ser propietario/s de la casa, recibir el dinero de la venta de la casa), sellado con la firma del otorgante u otorgantes y con la del notario dando fe de ello, el otorgante u otorgante **accede/n** por una parte al "**derecho de propiedad de la casa**", derecho que antes no tenía/n y aquellos otros "**a recibir un dinero por la venta**".

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus explicaciones!

Comment: ¡De nada!  Solo espero que lo hayas comprendido.

Comment: Sí, lo he entendido completamente, y es que Usted siempre explica de una manera fácil de entender para los no nativos ‍!

Answer (score 0):

Según mi experiencia, '***otorgante***' significa una persona *que asume la responsabilidad* de otra persona o personas.

Por ejemplo, si por algún motivo la *primera persona* no puede pagar, entonces el **otorgante** (*haciéndose responsable*) pagará en lugar de la primera persona.